# Web server router forwarding: port 80 closed - Linux Mint

Tags: linux, router, port-forwarding, webserver

I am new to web development. I have an Apache server on linux mint 17.2 that I can access locally. Now, I want to access the server from outside my network. I configure the router (TP-LINK WR340G) like the images below:

[Virtual Servers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Hp7Q.png)

[Port triggering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEdUW.png)

I tried to access this way: "myexternalIP:80" and doesn't work.

Using open port check tool returned: Port 80 is closed.

I already tried to open the port using the following:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

also:

```
sudo ufw allow 80
```

the port is still closed.

What am I doing wrong ?

If you need more info, just ask. Thanks.

Comment: First try to connect from outside your network. It looks like you have NAT problem. Second check Apache config. May be it works only on localhost.

Comment: @AlexAndersan I tried to connect from outside and doesn't work. How can I check the Apache config ?

Comment: Try sudo netstat -tulpan | grep 80  it will show you what process uses 80 port on which ip.

Comment: Also you should disable port triggering and set proper protocol (tcp) in your virtual server rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

I disable the port triggering in my router and works. But I still couldn`t access the server from outside.

I have an adsl modem + router, and the problem was in my modem, which was blocking the port. After some research, I was able to find the right settings to open the port and everything is working now.

Thanks for the help.